# Dijit Dialog Button Event Not Executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

I have a **[Dijit Dialog](http://jsfiddle.net/devdarin/YK6c3/6/)** (jsfiddle) created programmatically. When the Dialog Show is called i pass the id's for the buttons at runtime. I am trying to create click event functions to execute for the id's passed at runtime.

However the events are not executing. I would like to know how to attach a function to the dialog buttons.

**HTML**

```
<button id="show">Show Dialog</button>
```

**JS**

```
require([
    "dijit/form/CheckBox",
    "dijit/dijit",
    "dijit/form/Textarea",
    "dijit/form/FilteringSelect",
    "dijit/form/TextBox",
    "dijit/form/ValidationTextBox",
    "dijit/form/DateTextBox",
    "dijit/form/TimeTextBox",
    "dijit/form/Button",
    "dijit/form/RadioButton",
    "dijit/form/Form",
    "dijit/_DialogMixin"]);
require([
    "dojo/parser",
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/domReady!",
    "dojo/ready"],

function (parser, declare, ready, Dialog) {
    parser.parse();

    dojo.ready(function () {
        function showDialog(yesBtnId, noBtnId) {
            var dialog = new dijit.Dialog({
                title: 'Confirmation',
                content: '<table style= "width: 300px;">' +
                    '<tr>' +
                    '<th style="text-align:center; padding: 5px" colspan="2"><label>Are You Sure ?</label></th>' +
                    '</tr>' +
                    '<tr>' +
                    '<td style="text-align:center; padding: 5px"><button id=' + yesBtnId + '>Yes</button></td>' +
                    '<td style="text-align:center;padding: 5px"><button id= ' + noBtnId + '>No</button></td>' +
                    '</tr>' +
                    '</table>'
            });

            dialog.show();
        }

        var myShowBtn = {
            id: "show",
            onClick: function (evt) {

                showDialog('yesDelete', 'noDelete');
            }
        };
        dojo.query("#show").connect("onclick", myShowBtn.onClick);

        var myYesDelete = {
            id: "yesDelete",
            onClick: function (evt) {

                alert('hello its working....');

            }
        };

        dojo.query("#yesDelete").connect("onclick", myYesDelete.onClick);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to add an event handler for an element that does not exist yet when you call it, so the event handler is actually not bound because at that moment there's nothing to bind it to.

However, if you move the line:

```
dojo.query("#yesDelete").connect("onclick", myYesDelete.onClick);
```

Up to the `showDialog()` function (put it behind `dialog.show()`), then it will work as you can see in this updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YK6c3/7/).

Comment: how can i close the dialog in the "#yesDelete" function ?

Comment: I tried dijit.byId('dialog').destroy(); in the yesDelete function however i am getting TypeError: dijit.byId() undefined. Any ideas on this?

Comment: i got it working just needed to pass an id to the dialog at creation